# Curved border gets hidden due to navbar

Tags: html, css

I have html page with bootstrap navbar. There is a maincontainer which holds the site content. The main container has top padding applied to start its content after navbar. Because of this the curved border is not appearing at the top border. At the bottom, the curved border is working fine.

Is there any css solution to display the curved border on top border too?

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/LijoCheeran/cttstnob/3/

**HTML**

```
<body class="bodybackground">

 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ui-widget-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:2px;">
                    <div id="divBrandNameText" class="cookieFontGoogle" style="display:inline-block;color:#FFFFFF; vertical-align:central;">Brand</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">           
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="mainContainer" class="container body-content" style="padding-top:60px; background-color:#FFFFFF">
        Test
        <div style=" padding-top:100px;">
        A
        </div>
        B
    </div>

     </body>
```

CSS

```
  .navbar {
        background-color: #00A0F0;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #0078A0;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
            color: #737373;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #00A0F1;
    }
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #00A0F1;
    }
    .cookieFontGoogle {
        font: 200 50px/1.3 'Cookie', Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }

   #mainContainer {
    border-radius: 25px;
   }

   .bodybackground {
        background-color: #A9D5E7;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change padding to margin

```
<div id="mainContainer" class="container body-content" style="margin-top:60px; background-color:#FFFFFF">
```